# Which tools do you use to analyze waveform data from simulation or logic analyzer traces?

Tags: xilinx, logic-analyzer

I need to save Xilinx ChipScope waveforms for later review/analysis with my co-workers.

Wikipedia provided a handy [list of waveform tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform_viewer) but I am looking for user feedback on some of the strengths and weaknesses of specific tools.

To date, I have used the ChipScope export as [VCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_Change_Dump) option along with the VCD->WLF conversion tools built into ModelSim for this purpose. Currenty my needs are:

1. Store waveform data for later inspection and analysis of control signal logic
2. Compare/diff waveforms to identify differences between working and failing cases
3. Plot amplitude data over time
4. Plot one datum against another (e.g. constellation plot)
5. Use as input to ModelSim simulation

For context, my role is that of an embedded software developer working with the FPGA team at my company and I often find it helpful to look over waveforms I capture during a debug session with a coworker who worked on the module in question, especially when I believe it can be nailed down to a specific HW/SW interface. In such cases I want to capture and save off the waveforms when I do not have the right person at hand. It is also helpful for me to work through control signal logic on my own to identify possible issues.

I have started to use ModelSim for this analysis and review purpose and would be interested in alternatives and industry standard tools for this use case. We are a Xilinx shop with some smattering of Synopsys and MentorGraphics tools.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on your budget to make this a smaller task. Also define what needs you have for FFT, window eye pattern analysis, transient analysis, stats, RMS VI conversion etc.

Comment: @user11355 I added some detail and context for my use case. I hope this helps explain how I currently use the waveforms but I cannot genrally anticipate how the FPGA devs will want to use the waveform data.

Answer (score 1):

For the use cases you describe, I typically write python scripts to do the job.  There are good plotting facilities available in python (matplotlib et al) and it's often faster to write your own script if you're looking for something specific.  I don't have experience with the Xilinx tools, but if they can export the data to a format that's easy to parse, it's not a bad option.

Answer (score 0):

If you need great tools, I suggest you look at getting a budget to investigate and get trials periods. This is the best way.

Some free tools have great documentation but poor examples to see what is possible.
http://www.staticfreesoft.com/jmanual/index.html

In the old days we would just document the FPGA with a good logic Analyzer that offers deep conditional expressions in GUI interface for capturing events to compare with design spec.

Start with this company who is featured by Agilent.
http://www.amherst-systems.com/m1-apps-store-3.htm
They also have free waveform viewer tools.

You can justify the capital by deciding how it is going to cost the company if you don't get to market quickly or find bugs in the field.  Prepare them ahead of time that sophisticated accurate analysis takes time and debugging free software is not what you need to do. You need the best tools to make flawless complex products.